std::binary_search and lower_bound with array of unique_ptr
I've been trying to use std::binary_search and std::lower_bound on std::array<unique_ptr<int>> just to get to grips with it. I was having trouble with the following :
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<int>, 3> a = {std::make_unique<int>(1), 
    std::make_unique<int>(2), std::make_unique<int>(5)};

    auto t = std::binary_search(a.begin(), a.end(), 5, [] 
    (std::unique_ptr<int> x, std::unique_ptr<int> y) {
        return x.get() < y.get();
    });
return 0;
}

I'm trying to put my own comparison here, similar to how it would be done with something like std::sort. However when compiling this I have an error cannot convert argument 1 from 'const _Ty' to 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>'
What should I change to make this work?
EDIT : complete error message from Visual Studio
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   C2664   'bool thng_already::<lambda_1>::operator ()(std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>,std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const _Ty' to 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=int
        ]   Proj    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\algorithm 7028        

When replacing 5 with std::make_unique<int>(5) we have a different error
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   C2280   'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function  Proj    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\algorithm 7028        


dont take the unique ptr by value.

please post a [mcve] and include the complete error message in the question

5 is not a unique_ptr

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I'm not sure how I can make this example more minimal but I'll try making 5 a unique_ptr

it is too minimal. Why remove the includes and main? Its only 3 lines, but anybody who wants compile this code will have to add them back in.

@AnthonyML -- C++ is a complex language with many rules.  If you skimp on the headers, just that alone could make the difference between what compiles and what fails if we were to manually add the headers back in.  That's why you need to have everything in the C++ code samples that you post.

@PaulMcKenzie sure thing. I've added the headers I'm using and my main function etc

Why not read the manual for finding the answer prior asking a question on SO? The signature of the predicate function should be equivalent to the following: bool pred(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);

@273K sorry I missed that. I've always found lambda functions confusing in this way and had just forgotten that unique_ptr can't be copied.

There are three issues:

Your lambda takes its parameters by value. This implies that the binary_search implementation has to copy the arguments when passing them to the lambda. Can you copy unique_ptr? No. That's why it's not working. Take the arguments by const reference instead.

The lambda cannot accept 5 as one of its arguments since 5 is not a unique_ptr<int>

You Compare x.get() < y.get(). get() returns the raw pointer to the integer, so you compare pointers, not the values that these pointers point to. I assume you mean *x < *y to compare the integers instead


int main() {
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<int>, 3> a = {
            std::make_unique<int>(1), 
            std::make_unique<int>(2),
            std::make_unique<int>(5)};
    auto t = std::binary_search(a.begin(), a.end(),
            std::make_unique<int>(5),
            [](const std::unique_ptr<int>& x, const std::unique_ptr<int>& y) {
        return *x < *y;
    });
    return 0;
}

Feel free to shorten the lambda declaration to [](const auto& x, const auto& y) and rely on type deduction.
Avoiding the temporary allocation
Calling make_unique<int>(5) does a temporary allocation that is not strictly necessary. To avoid it, we need to augment the comparator to accept int and std::unique_ptr<int> as its arguments in either order. This is probably the easiest approach to do so:
    struct Compare {
        bool operator()(const std::unique_ptr<int>& left, int right) const
        { return *left < right; }
        bool operator()(int left, const std::unique_ptr<int>& right) const
        { return left < *right; }
    };
    auto t = std::binary_search(begin, end, val, Compare{});


[] (const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) is better

@273K That's more of a style question, and one that I don't necessary agree with, especially when writing code with or for beginners who may benefit from more explicit type checks and may have a harder type deducing types. But I've added it as an alternative suggestion. For OP, changing from unique_ptr<int> to const unique_ptr<int>& is the shortest fix and closest to their code style, so I'm sticking with it

You only need int in one direction for some algorithms

The predicate will be used to compare elements in the array with the to be found value, ie you can think of it like this
auto comp =  [] (std::unique_ptr<int> x, std::unique_ptr<int> y) {
    return x.get() < y.get();
};

auto value = 5;

Then the algorithm will do something along the line of:
for (const auto& x : a) { 
    if (comp(x,value)) ...

This has two issues: 5 is not a std::unique_ptr<int>. And you cannot pass the std::unique_ptrs by value. Unique pointers cannot be copied. You should pass them by reference.
For more details and a more accurate possible implementation I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search.
